# The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.facebook.com' in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

[Please click the link for see the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeZOs.png)When we sign-up through the Facebook in nopcommerce.

We are successfully login to facebook and also conform app authentication after that we are redirected to our website. While redirecting to our website we got this error.

Comment: Can you include the error details in text? That way it will be searchable and it is more likely that you will get a response.

Comment: Sir, I have uploaded the image of the error. Please see on it.

Comment: Don't use images for that. Images are not searchable, so no one will find your question. Copy the error text into the question.

Comment: Okay Sir. So when i was singing through facebook and after that returning in my web page at that time it was showing error like :  "Server Error in '/' application" in nopcommerce.